# The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server in ODOO python

Tags: proxy, odoo, reverse-proxy, odoo-10, connection-timeout

When I try to print preview the general ledger report in ODOO. This error(attached the screenshot below)pops up after loading for some 5 minutes. The datas will be huge and I knew it takes time to process and throw the output. How to fix this issue in ODOOv10 or whatever the version is?

Error Screen shot:
[image: Proxy error]

Comment: attached the screenshot below) - didn't find any screenshot.

Comment: Hi, I have attached the screenshot.@HardikgiriGoswami